# Photodiode JFET amplifier stage in pinch off?

Tags: amplifier, photodiode, jfet, biasing

In the circuit below, it seems that the JFET is biased in a regime with very low current (pinched off?).

With respect to most designs I came across, this one uses rather large source and drain resistors (factor 10 more than usual). I think it is pinched off by this biasing ([datasheet](http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-3532802171181169245) gives cutoff voltage of \$V_{gs}=-1.1V\$ with \$I_d=10\mu A\$).

- What are the advantages? (Why is it used rarely? It is a rare configuration, isn't it?)
- How can one calculate operating point and amplification factor from data sheet parameters?

I understand that in pinch off, the drain current is exponentially dependent on \$V_{gs}\$, i.e. \$I_d(V_{gs})=I_0\exp\left(\frac{V_{gs}}{n\cdot k_B T/q}\right)\$. But, I never find \$n\$ mentioned in the data sheets. Also most SPICE models seem to fix it to 1. Is this okay? I heard somewhere that it can vary from 1 to 3ish.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft5j3Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(The schematic is adapted from schematics of a lightgun that I found on the web. D1 could also be a phototransistor or forward biased, but I don't think this matters!?)

[Question edited after discussion with FakeMoustache below.]

Comment: *JFET in weak inversion/sub-threshold regime.* As far as I know weak inversion / sub threshold is for MOSFETs. This is a JFET. JFETs are mostly depletion type so normally **ON** when Vgs = 0. In this circuit the JFET is biased such that Vgs is slightly negative which is a **very normal** mode of operation for a JFET.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: What makes me believe it is sub threshold (which AFIR exists for all FET types, but just starts at more negative Vgs for JFETs) is the large resistor values of Rs and Rd. Essentially, max. 10uA (DC) flow. Normally, I see resistor values of 1 to 10k in similar circuits.

Comment: The difference between weak and strong inversion in MOSFET is in the value of Vgs, it has nothing to do with the resulting Id

Comment: Aren't the two interrelated in this circuit due to the feedback caused by Rs? The 2SK104 has a typical cutoff voltage of Vgs=-1.1V, with Id=10uA [datasheet](http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-3532802171181169245).

Comment: No, lookup what an inversion layer is. It applies to a MOS structure. This is a JFET, it does not have a MOS structure, it has a PN junction which is ”pinched” by the gate's depletion layer. JFETs do not have inversion let alone weak or strong inversion. Again: look up what inversion means and notice how it needs a MOS structure.

Comment: OK, now I think I understand your point. I was wrongly using the term "weak inversion" for JFETs. Thank you for pointing this out. Can we agree on "subthreshold" (like in Art of Electronics, 3rd, chap. 3.3)? - I would change the question then accordingly.

Comment: *Can we agree on "subthreshold"* Nope, because this circuit has  JFET, which does not have a threshold voltage. It does have a **pinch off** voltage but that is different. Do separate your MOSFETs from your JFETs, they're **completely** different devices !!!

Comment: "Subtreshold" is what I read (specifically on JFETs, Art of Electronics, 3rd, chap. 3.3), but I am open to suggestions. How do you propose to change the question to become more correct? I still think that this device is operated in a region where Id is exponentially dependent on Vgs and I asked this question because I would like to understand why it is biased like this and how to calculate the operating parameters and would like to update the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I only have the 2nd edition, only section 3.04 mentions "subthreshold" and that **only** applies to MOSFETs. In my opinion it would have been better to put all the JFET related things in a separate chapter.

Comment: @magnustron, Jfets are like depletion mode mosfets.  (Except for not being able to raise the V-GS above ~0.6V)  Keep reading AoE!   (fake moustache seems to be confused about the similarity.)  This looks like a pretty standard common source amp... see figure 3.28 in AoE3.)

Comment: @FakeMoustache, you seem to be confused about the similarity between depletion mode mosfets and Jfets.  I would suggest rereading AoE2.. and buying a copy of AoE3. (If you are serious about electronics.)  (It seems like we've had this discussion in the past.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I can assure you that I'm not confused about depletion mode MOSFETs and JFETs. *If you are serious about electronics* Ahum, I design ICs for a living, there isn't much in AoE that I don't know already. The confusion here started from applying MOSFET modes of operation (like weak inversion) to a JFET.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Yes, topology is pretty standard. Still, the resistor values are too high, which is precisely what I would like to understand better.

Comment: *the resistor values are too high* Explain to my why that is so. What would the advantage be of having lower value resistors ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache I _think_ they make the transistor go into pinch off (as written in the edited question). I _assume_ these values _are_ advantageous (in this application at least) over lower values, but do not understand _why_ (part 1 of my question).

Comment: Near pinch off the dependency of Id on Vgs is the greatest, meaning you will have the **highest transconductance** and therefore the **highest gain**. Especially in combination with a high value Rd. The small quiescent Id means Rs also needs a high value. If Rs had a low value, Vgs will be close to zero meaning no pinch-off meaning less gain. Rs is shorted by Cs to have high gain for AC signals.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation.Turn it into an answer to let me accept!

Comment: @FakeMoustache, sorry, I mostly just use IC's :^)  (And I'm not very good at transistor level design.)  magnustron,  Keep reading AoE3, they explain it there... More gain, as FM says above.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I know, but why is this seen so rarely? And how to calculate the operating point and gain without knowing n? Is this good design practice, given the large spread of pinch off voltages?

Comment: Actually, transconductance (id/vgs) is lower at lower Id, but the gain is still higher due to the larger Rd, right?

Comment: Yes the gain is roughly gm*Rd so a higher Rd directly helps. For larger Id indeed gm (transconductance) increases with Id but that is in saturation mode. Here the JFET does not operate in sat. mode but in triode mode. To be in sat. mode the resistors would have to have a lower value so that a larger Id can flow. But then the gain would be much less.